# What is the use of special sequences,e.g \number in python?

Tags: python, regex, sequence

why the second print result is None:

```
import re
pattern=r"(.+) \1" #notice that there is whitespace here before the backslash
match=re.match(pattern,"abc abc")
if match:
    print(1)   #1 was printed
match=re.match(pattern,"abc abd")
print(match)   # None
```

Additionally,please give me another example for the usage of '\2'.
Thx a lot.

Comment: You can't use `\2` with only one capture group

Comment: yes,I mean,plz show an additional example,not the one I posted here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in second example you have different values, `abc` and `abd`.

According to py mans, `\number`

> Matches the contents of the group of the same number

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html

This means, it matches **the contents** of the group, not group's regular expression, so the second part is expected to be the same. This is the way to find other occurrences of the match.

Example for `\2` is below:

`(.+) (.+) \1 \2`

will match

`hello kitty hello kitty`

Comment: Yeah,very clear,I see.

Comment: @EricBen *"Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!"* - [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: @Johan. You need 15 rep for that.